# Facebook Business Extension

Tags: facebook, opencart

https://github.com/facebookarchive/Facebook-For-OpenCart

Admin Permission Required
You don't have permission to edit these settings. Reach out to the admin of the Business Manager 'Website Tasarım' to gain access.

Hello.

How many times have I uninstalled the plugin, reinstalled it, cleared the cache, I can't get around this problem. I'm looking for a business code in the database and I can't find it. How do I break the connection here? I have nothing to do with the business that appears here. When I asked Facebook, they said there doesn't seem to be a problem on our side.

Admin Permission Required

I aim to solve this problem

Comment: Have you granted permissions in admin System/Users/User Groups for administrator?Check all checkboxes and save settings.

Comment: Yes, I did. The problem is not there. When I asked the plugin owner, he said that the problem was caused by facebook permissions.